# Java decision problems

Tags: java, if-statement

I have created a small program in Java, but when I try to run it, the compiler gives me the following message:

```
bad operand types for binary operator '>'
```

Also, I can't understand the meaning of an other message:

```
error: class Exercise1 is public, should be declared in a file named Exercise1.java
```

The code is in the follow lines:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            // υλοποίηση της άσκησης
            int guess = 0;
            while (guess != random) {
                System.out.println("Δώσε έναν αριθμό μεταξύ 1 και 100:");
                guess = scan.nextInt();
                if (guess < random) {
                    System.out.println(guess + "είναι χαμηλό. Ξαναπροσπάθησε!");
                    System.out.println("Δώσε έναν αριθμό μεταξύ" + guess + "και" + random);
                } else if (guess > random) {
                    System.out.println(guess + "είναι υψηλό. Ξαναπροσπάθησε!");
                    System.out.println("Δώσε έναν αριθμό μεταξύ" + guess + "και" + random);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Συγχαρητήρια!");
                }
                playAgain = scan.next();
            }
            while (playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) ;
            scan.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`random` is not an `int`. Use `random.nextInt()` to generate a random value, and use that.

```
Random randomGen = new Random();
int random = randomGen.nextInt(100) + 1; // <-- 1 to 100
```

Then your existing code should work as is.